# Discord.js: How to temporarily activate an Event in an external js-file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

As tomorrow is the first of April, I thought of a tiny joke for my discord bot:
The bot has a command that outputs "Say thank you". After that, the user who executed the command needs to say "Thank you", "Thanks" or whatever within a minute. If he doesn't, something else will get executed.

This is everything I got atm. I don't know if a timeout will do, I want to check if the event found the "Thanks" within that minute

```
var thankWords = ['thank', 'thank you', 'thanks'];

                    for (int i = 0; i < thankWords.Length, i++) {
                        if(message.content.includes(thankWords[i])) {
                           //sets a "saidThanks"-boolean to true
                        }
                    }

                setTimeout(() => {

                    //checks if "saidThanks" is true and does stuff if not so

                }, 60000);
```

Now my problem is, my bot commands are in a seperate folder, whenever the "onMessage"-Event gets executes with my prefix, the bot looks for a file named like the command and executed it.
So how can I bring the "onMessage" Event to this external js-file, and activate it for a minute, where it checks, if the "Thank you" gets written in chat?

Comment: What do you mean by external file ? Do you want to load another instance of node in child-process or just get the code like require('./myCode.js') ?

Comment: Actually, I just need to activate an event for a minute, I figured out how to do the external jar stuff